Xamarin WebRTC multiple Peer connections
I have an Xamarin Android application. I have implemented WebRTC using the Xam.WebRtc.Android library. I was able to establish a peer connection successfully between Peer A and Peer B., I have implemented dictionaries for my peer connections as it is a mesh topology implementation, as soon as I add Peer C to the connection the following flow occurs, should it just not be as easy as new Peer joined change details between all the same way as the first two complete it and all works?? I am also sequentially calling the two active peers to establish new peer connections with each so I don't have any issues with Offers/Answers being messed up.

Switch on Peer A
Switch on Peer B
Peer A and Peer B creates peer connection and voice data goes back and forth
Switch on Peer C
Peer A and Peer B can connect any more connection is broken
6 Peer A and Peer C can connect and talk
Peer B can talk to C but C can't talk back to Peer B only to Peer A

Please advise any assistance would be very welcomed.
I have tried to implement the sequential connections and the dictionaries so multiple peer connections can be established for each peer, but the result is still the same. They do connect but somewhere along the line the connection between Peer A and Peer B is disrupted and I have no clue where this is happening.
